# UIView removeFromSuperView animation delay

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview, commitanimations

I have a method which animates one of the subviews of `UIWindow` and then removes it from `UIWindow` using `removeFromSuperview`. But when I put `removeFromSuperview` after animation block, the animation never shows, because `removeFromSuperview` removes the `UIView` from `UIWindow` before the animation plays :-( How can I delay `removeFromSuperview` so the animation plays first, and then subview is removed? I tried `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];` after animation block but that didn't have desired effect, because animation sleeps too for some reason.

My code for this method:

```
  - (void) animateAndRemove
    {
     NSObject *mainWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];

     [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8]; 
     UIView *theView = nil;
     for (UIView *currentView in [mainWindow subviews])
     {
      if (currentView.tag == 666)
      {
       currentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.8 green:0.8 blue:0.8 alpha:0.0];
       theView = currentView;
       }
     }
     [UIView setAnimationTransition:  UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:theView cache:YES];
      [UIView commitAnimations]; 



 //[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];

 [theView removeFromSuperview];


    }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should use the delegation mechanism in animation blocks to decide what to do when the animation ends. For your case, use

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:theView];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
 ....
```

This ensures `[theView removeFromSuperview]` will be called after the animation is completed.

Answer (score 7):

If you're targetting iOS 4.0 upwards you can use animation blocks:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
     animations:^{view.alpha = 0.0;}
     completion:^(BOOL finished){ [view removeFromSuperview]; }];
```

(above code comes from Apple's UIView documentation)